# need to get data from multiple mySQL tables grouping by date

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables

1st: `order`
columns: `id`, `date`, `price`

2nd: `paypal`
columns: `id`, `posted_date`, `amount`

the columns `date` and `posted_date` contains the full date & time details; day/month/year hrs:minute:seconds

I need to get the data by grouping by the day from the both tables

1. `order`.`date` (day by day)
2. count all orders from `order` table for each day
3. sum of all `price` records from `order` table for each day
4. sum of all `amount` records from the another table `paypal` table for the same days

I can't imagine if I should use join, union, union all, or just merge by comma

Comment: Add sample table data and expected output. Also show us your current query, and tell us what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one working for me :)

```
SELECT DATE(O.`date`) AS Dates,
COUNT(O.order) AS Order_count,
SUM(O.price) as Total_Price,
(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM paypal WHERE DATE(O.`date`)=`posted_date`) AS Total_Amount
FROM order O
GROUP BY DATE(O.`date`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT DATE(O.`dater`) AS Dates,
    COUNT(O.orders) AS Order_count,
    SUM(O.price) as Total_Price,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM paypal WHERE DATE(O.`dater`)=`posted_date`) AS Total_Amount
    FROM orders O
    GROUP BY DATE(O.`dater`)
```

Note:(I have used column `dater` instead of column `date`)
Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks for your support, I got the idea from your code :)